Angular App reloads immediately when browser tab is out of focus
My blogging application reloads when i switch tab to a new tab. The moment the tab with the application is out of focus, the application reloads and return to the base route.
For example if I am filling out a Rich text editor on the '/content' route or the form on the '/profile' and i switch tabs to get information for another tab, when i return, the app reloads to '/' route
I have attempeted cache the last active route. This is implemented in app.component.ts
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'code_to_blog';



  constructor(private router: Router) {

  }
  ngOnInit() {


    this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        localStorage.setItem('lastRoute', event.urlAfterRedirects);
      }
    });

    // Check if there's a stored route when the app initializes
    const lastRoute = localStorage.getItem('lastRoute');
    if (lastRoute ) {
      // Navigate to the stored route if it's different from the current route
      this.router.navigateByUrl(lastRoute);
    }

    Listen for visibility change events (when the user leaves or returns to the tab)
    document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', () => {
      if (!document.hidden) {
        console.log('VISIBILITY')
        // When the tab becomes visible again, restore the route
        const lastRoute = localStorage.getItem('lastRoute');
        if (lastRoute && this.router.url !== lastRoute) {
          this.router.navigateByUrl(lastRoute);
        }
      }
    });


  
  }

This the route is cached but the reload still happens.
I experince this reload on all routes except, /dashboard, /landing, /login, /register.
I also  tried removing the AuthGuard and the issue still is persisting
My router file is

export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'dashboard',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
  {
    path: 'register',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./features/auth/auth.routes').then((m) => m.registerRoutes),
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./features/auth/auth.routes').then((m) => m.loginRoutes),
    //canActivate:[loginGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'landing',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./features/auth/auth.routes').then((m) => m.landingRoutes),
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./features/blog/blog.routes').then((m) => m.blogListRoutes),
    canActivate: [authGuard],
    data:{reuse:true,store:true}
  },
  {
    path: 'all',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./features/blog/blog.routes').then((m) => m.blogListAllRoutes),
  },
  {
    path: 'create-blog',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./features/blog/blog.routes').then((m) => m.blogCreateRoutes),
    canActivate: [authGuard],
  },
  {
    path: 'view-blog',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./features/blog/blog.routes').then((m) => m.blogViewRoutes),
  },
  {
    path: 'content',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./features/blog/blog.routes').then((m) => m.blogEditRoutes),
    canActivate: [authGuard],
    data:{reuse:true,store:true}
  },
  {
    path: 'profile',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./features/userProfile/userProfile.routes').then(
        (m) => m.updateUserProfileRoutes
      ),
    canActivate: [authGuard],
    data:{reuse:true}
  },
  {
    path: 'linkedin',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./features/blog/blog.routes').then((m) => m.LinkedinRoutes),
    canActivate: [authGuard],
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./shared/shared.route').then((m) => m.sharedRoutes),
  }
];



I have also attempted the to use implement the routeReuseStrategy
@Injectable()
export class CustomReuseStrategy implements RouteReuseStrategy {
    shouldReuseRoute(future: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, curr: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
        throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
    }

    store(snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): DetachedRouteHandle | null {
        // Add logic to determine which routes to store (e.g., by route data)
        if (snapshot.data['store']) {
            return { handle: snapshot.component, selector: snapshot.routeConfig?.path };
        }
        return null;
    }

    shouldAttach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
        return !!route.routeConfig && !!route.data['reuse'];
    }

    shouldDetach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
        return !!this.store(route); // Detach only if the route is stored
    }

    retrieve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): DetachedRouteHandle | null {
        // Retrieve the previously stored handle based on route information

        const routeConfig = route.routeConfig?.path
        if(routeConfig){
        const stored = localStorage.getItem(routeConfig);
        if (stored) {
            return JSON.parse(stored);
        }
     

        }

        return null;
    }
}

And added it to the list of providers in app.config.ts
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  
  providers: [
    provideHttpClient(),
    provideZoneChangeDetection({ eventCoalescing: true }), 
    provideClientHydration(withHttpTransferCacheOptions({
      includePostRequests: true
    })),
    provideRouter(routes), 
    provideStore(reducers, { metaReducers }),
    provideEffects(authEffects,userProfileEffects,blogEffects,linkedinAuthEffects), 
    provideStoreDevtools({
       maxAge: 25, 
       logOnly: !isDevMode(),
       autoPause:true,
       trace:false,
       traceLimit:75 }), 
    provideAnimationsAsync(), 
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: CustomReuseStrategy }

  ]
};


But there is still not change

Can you share a codesandbox or somthing to reproduce it?

Please paste full code of app.component.ts, and also paste code of your router file app.routes.ts.

@zdd i have included the router file and updated the app.component.ts

@ibokkegbo which route was reloaded? I didn't see myForm in your route file.

@zdd All are reloaded except, login, register, dashboard and landing

What version of Angular is this please?  And does the reuse service need to be direct injected into the components which are going "out of focus"?
